# navigate to a directory and assign its name to a variable using explorer in a batch file

Tags: batch

I am running a .bat file.  I would like to use explorer to select a directory and assign it to a variable without closing the .bat file or changing the directory it is executing in. 
I have tried Explorer /E c:
but the batch file closes on me.  Also, I do not want to execute a file, just assign a selected directory path to a variable.

Comment: You can invoke a vbs or powershell from batch to get a [file-folder-chooser-dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885132/file-folder-chooser-dialog-from-a-windows-batch-script)

Comment: what will you use the variable for? if it's nothing in the script you may just need to edit an environment variable on your system